# Regex of digit followed by char times the matched number

Tags: regex

Please assist with matching the following pattern: 1 digit, followed by characters times the value of the digit.

For example:

```
Valid string - 3aaa4bbbb2cc (3 times "a",4 times "b", etc. )
Invalid string - 3aaa4bbb2cc ("a"-->3 times,b -->3 times instead of 4, "c" --> 2 times)
```

My intuitive thought was to use grouping as a reference for digit value, but it doesn't work.
In my case "$" being interpreted as end of sting and not as reference to the 1st match:
/((\d)\w{$1})+/g

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regex cannot unfortunately interpret text as a number for matching purposes - your only choice would be to create 9 different alternations, one per digit. (e.g. `1.|2(.)\1{1}|3(.)\2{2}|...`)

Comment: Are you using a programming language?

Comment: Thank you @nneonneo, I thought there is an easier way to deal with it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, nope just writing script in bash that will read files structured of string lengths and patterns.

Comment: This would be fairly straightforward to handle using something like Java or Python, but it would be more than a one-liner.

Comment: `sok()( echo "$1" | perl -nle 's/(\d+)((\D)\3*)/!!($1-length($2))/eg;exit!!$_' && echo "Valid string - $1" || echo "Invalid string - $1" ); sok 3aaa4bbbb2cc; sok 3aaa4bbb2cc`